# get_the_ID() doesnt work

Tags: php, wp-query

Here is my query loop:

```
<?php
$query = new \WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
?>
```

I want to call $post for this:

```
<div>
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[svg-flag flag="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ozellikler_text', true ) . '"]' ); ?>
</div>
```

I tried to call it with this:

```
<?php
function get_the_ID() {
    $post = get_post();
    return ! empty( $post ) ? $post->ID : false;
}
?>
```

the code doesn't call it. It gives the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_the_ID() (previously declared in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_the_ID](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) is a WordPress core fuction in the global namespace, so you can't make a second function called `get_the_ID` as it won't know which one to use.  You should just call get_the_ID() without writing a new function.

For your example code, you could do something like this:

```php
<div>
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[svg-flag flag="' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ozellikler_text', true ) . '"]' ); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have such thing as `$post->ID`, you have `$query->$post->ID` in your WP_Query result:

```
<?php
$my_post_meta = get_post_meta(
    $query->$post->ID, // note this
    'ozellikler_text',
    true
);

echo do_shortcode( '[svg-flag flag="' . $my_post_meta . '"]' );
```

Second, as already written in the error text, you can't redeclare already declared built-in function. Simply use it:

```
<?php
$my_post_meta = get_post_meta(
    get_the_ID(), // use the built-in function
    'ozellikler_text',
    true
);

echo do_shortcode( '[svg-flag flag="' . $my_post_meta . '"]' );
```